# Spring batch: infrastructure

Tags: spring, batch-processing

I am reading Spring user guide. I came across below statement. I confused by statement "let the framework take care of infrastructure". I mean infrastructure means any Hardware..Nw in Spring Batch is framework, where does infrastructure came in picture

Batch developers use the Spring programming model: concentrate on business logic; let the
framework take care of infrastructure

Please help me in understanding/

Answer (score 5):

If you will read the complete documentation, you will get:

[image: Spring Batch Layered Architecture]
Figure: Spring Batch Layered Architecture

> This layered architecture highlights three major high level
>   components: Application, Core, and Infrastructure. The application
>   contains all batch jobs and custom code written by developers using
>   Spring Batch. The Batch Core contains the core runtime classes
>   necessary to launch and control a batch job. It includes things such
>   as a JobLauncher, Job, and Step implementations. Both Application and
>   Core are built on top of a common infrastructure. This infrastructure
>   contains common readers and writers, and services such as the
>   RetryTemplate, which are used both by application
>   developers(ItemReader and ItemWriter) and the core framework itself.
>   (retry)

[spring-batch reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Batch framework is designed to cater to batch applications that run on a daily basis in enterprise organizations. It helps to leverage the benefits of the Spring framework along with the advance services. Spring Batch is mainly used to process huge volume of data. It offers better performance and is highly scalable using different optimization and partition techniques. It also provides advantage over logging/tracing, transaction management, job processing statistics, job restart, steps, and resource management. By using the Spring programming model, I can write the business logic and let the framework take care of infrastructure.

Spring Batch includes three components: batch application, batch execution environment and batch infrastructure.

The Application component contains all the batch jobs and custom code written using Spring Batch.

The Core component contains the core runtime classes necessary to launch and control a batch job. It includes things such as a JobLauncher, Job, and Step implementations. Both Application and Core are built on top of a common infrastructure.

The Infrastructure contains readers, writers and services which are used both by application and the core framework itself. They include things like ItemReader, ItemWriter and MongoTemplate. To use the Spring Batch framework, you need only to configure and customize the XML files. All existing core services should be easy to replace or extend, without any impact to the infrastructure layer.

-from Devx

I hope this would help you understand how it works.